# Row not adding to matrix in while loop in sympy

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

The aim of this program is to build a 3x3 matrix which then reduces additional rows, but, for some reason, after the second row is added to M in the while loop, it replaces it with the new row, rather than adding a third row, and, then, reducing additional (most likely 3) vectors after that.  Here's the code:

```
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_unicode= True)
A = []
def reduceOneRow(M):
    k = 0
    for i in range(k,min(M.shape)-1):
        if M[i,i]!=0 or i ==2:
            for j in range(k,min(M.shape)-1):
                T = Matrix([M.row(j+1)-(M[j+1,i]/M[i,i])*M.row(i)])
                A.append(M[j+1]/M[i,i])
                M.row_del(j+1)
                M = M.row_insert(j+1,T)

            k = k+1
        else:
            i = i+1
    return M
# M = Matrix([[1,1,1],[1,4,7],[3,2,5]])
# reduceOneRow(M)
# A
#The following block of code generates a list of monomials, but not in reverse
#lexicagraphical order. This can be fixed later.  Ultimately, I'd like to
#make it it's own function

sigma = symbols('x1:4')
D = [1]
for d in D:
    for s in sigma:
        if s*d not in D:
            D.append(s*d)
    if len(D) > 20:
        break

# print(D)
# print(D[9].subs([('x1',4),('x2',2),('x3',3)]))
#We begin with the set up described in C1
P = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
G = []
Q = []
S = []
L = [1]
M = Matrix([])
#Here we being step C2.
while L != []:#what follows this while statement is the loop C2-C5 and back

    t = L[0]
    L.remove(L[0])
    K = Matrix([]) #K is a kind of bucket matrix

    if t==1: #this block generates the firs line in M.  It had to be separate
        for j in range(len(P)):#because of the way sympy works. 1 is int, rather
            K = K.col_insert(j,Matrix([1])) #than a symbol

    else: #here we generate all other rows of M, using K for the name of the rows
        for p in P:
            K = K.col_insert(0,Matrix([t.subs([(sigma[0],p[0]),(sigma[1],p[1]),(sigma[2],p[2])])]))

                # K = K.col_insert(i,Matrix([t.subs([(sigma[0],p[0]),(sigma[1],p[1]),(sigma[2],p[2])]))
    M = M.row_insert(min(M.shape)+1,K) #K gets added to M
    M
    A = []
    reduceOneRow(M)#row reduces M and produces the ai in C3

    sum = 0
    for n in range(len(A)):
        sum = sum + A[n]*S[n]
    V = M.row(-1)

    if V == zeros(1,len(V)):
        G.append(t - sum)
        M.row_del(-1)

    else:
        S.append(t-sum)
        Q.append(t)

        for i in range(1,4):
            #if not t*D[i] == Q[0]:
                L.append(t*D[i])
    L
print('G =',' ',G,' ','Q =',Q)
```

Comment: You need to test that code line by line to make sure it's doing what you expect.  While I'm not that familiar with the `sympy.Matrix` class, you probably aren't doing anything advanced.  You could add a number of display lines, or replicate the steps in an interactive session.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.  I changed 'reduceRowOne(M)' to 'M = reduceRowOne'.  Ugh.

Thank you all who took a look at this!